# Java xml schema design

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I would like to generate polymorphic java classes of XSD. Is it possible develop polymorphic xml schema that support following xml?

So that i would have Object oriented inherited class structure...

Following would be possible scenario:

```
<Product>
    <Car>
            <FastCar>
                    <engine> </engine>
            </FastCar>
    </Car>
</Product>

<Product>
    <Car>
            <SlowCar>
                    <engine> </engine>
            </SlowCar>
    </Car>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with jaxb, specifically the xjc utility which will take an XSD file as a parameter, and some details (package, path, etc) for your desired java classes.

http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.6/